# OAuth2 Single-sign-on component, force reauthentication

Tags: php, authentication, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on

Right now I have a Abstract Adapter that handles all the different social medias, the social media adapters just hold the information and pass that to the abstract adapter that then uses OAuth2 to authenticate the user and allows API calls to be made. I want to FORCE the user to reauthenticate everytime they try to login, link or unlink an account. How do I tell OAuth2 I want them to reauth everytime? This is what I pass right now for the authentication:

```
$this->_oauth = new \League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\GenericProvider(array(
        'clientId'                => $this->_key,
        'clientSecret'            => $this->_secret,
        'redirectUri'             => $this->getObject('request')->getBaseUrl() . $this->_redirect_uri,
        'urlAuthorize'            => $this->_authorize_uri,
        'urlAccessToken'          => $this->_access_uri,
        'urlResourceOwnerDetails' => ''
    ));
```

So my question, everything works fine, linking, unlinking and signing into an account which has been linked with a social media using that social media. But how do I force the user to reauth everytime even if they logged into Facebook 5 minutes ago and Facebook knows it still has a active session? (Same thing for all other social medias, Facebook is just an example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that besides for Facebook and Google it's impossible to force reauth. OAuth2 also offers nothing for this.