# PHP - OAuth2 force Github reauthorizations (relogging)

Tags: php, github, oauth, single-sign-on

For security reasons I need Github to ask the user to login again to confirm it's actually the owner of the GitHub account trying to use the OAuth2 on my current single-sign-on project.

For Linkedin and Google I am having the same issue, for Facebook there is an option in developers.facebook.com that force reauth for OAuth2 everytime but for now I've used this code to force Facebook Reauth:

```
public function getRequestParams() {
    return array(
        'auth_type' => 'reauthenticate'
    );
}
```

I've been searching all afternoon yesterday and have also spend my whole morning on it again now. This is a MANDATORY thing for the web application of the customer, the application MUST reauth for Linkedin/Facebook/Github/Google, I can probably get it to work with Linkedin/Google but I don't see any solution with Github.

Simply asking for a new token doesn't do anything either because then the Github account is still logged in and will just automatically authorize it. And obviously I can't temper with the cookies from a other URL.

Is there anyway I can do this? I am pretty sure there is no way at all to do it via a OAuth2 Parameter (or else I would be able to add it to my abstract class allowing it to work with any SingleSignOn I add, which would be optimal but seemingly impossible).

I've asked a similar question here for OAuth2 but I believe it's just not possible [OAuth2 Single-sign-on component, force reauthentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36036148/oauth2-single-sign-on-component-force-reauthentication)

But specificly for Github, any possibility to force the user to login everytime there is an OAuth call made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've been work quite a lot more on our SSO adapter and I've had to conclude that it is impossible to do this. These are the two conclusions I came to.

1. OAuth2 is a framework that does not offer any functionality, you use it for example to make something abstract and use the same methods for Github/Facebook/Linkedin/etc without having to use 5 different SDK's
2. If the Social Media doesn't offer the functionality then you can't do it. Unless you want to do some almost border line-hacking and destroy the users sessions/cookies whatever. Even if it was possible it possibly isn't legal and it surely isn't user friendly.

We've ended up accepting that there's a small chance that someone can exploit logging in to another users account like that, but considering you need physical access or have to be able to remote control someones computer we decide that this is something that the user is supposed to control and we really can't do more about unless we do not offer the social media at all.